# Where can I find more information about the tests made to verify the functionality of the Tenserflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm in a group project in school and we are currently using the [tensorflow object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). The object detection works great but we are very interested in how the developers of this API have tested it. Is there anyone who has contributed to the project or knows where I can find more information about testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the API is well tested.

You can find the tests of each module in a python file at the same level and with the same name + the suffix "_test"

As an example the module:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_lib.py

Is tested in:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_lib_test.py